# how to store list of files in mysql database and display them based on users role(s)

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, roles

I am an asp.net mvc newbie. I haven't really done anything since classic asp. I want to display a list of files from a Mysql database based on the users role. So far I have created two tables some files will be viewable by more than one role. I am also using the MySql Membership Provider

Table **Files**

```
FileID, FileName, FilePath
```

Table **FilesRole**

```
FileID, RoleID
```

I am thinking I can add a file to the files table and then for each role that has access to that file I will need to add the fileID to the FilesRole table and also get the `RoleID` from the `my_aspnet_roles` table and add that to.

and then somehow when someone goes to view the files it will grab the ID of every role they are in and then get a list of files from the db

I have no idea where to start on this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That all looks good to me, just keep moving :)

Comment: lots of places you could start. In codefirst you've messed up by creating the tables :( Google a tutorial, way too broad a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me get you up to speed:

## 1. Create users and add them to roles

Webdeveloper Express and Visual Studio have a Web administration tool for your website:

> To access the Web Site Administration Tool, on the Website menu, click ASP.Net Configuration.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0.aspx

You can add users and roles and add-users-to-roles from there.

## 2. Create database records (assuming you have a mysql administration panel of some sort)

Now create some file records in your database and create create some association records between files and roles. I would use `RoleName` instead of `RoleID` because the default RoleProvider interface works with `string` names.

## 3. Learn how to query the mysql database from ASP.NET

Read this for instance: http://support.discountasp.net/KB/a358/how-to-query-a-mysql-database-in-aspnet.aspx

## 4. Create the correct query based on the Users roles

```
string[] userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

// creates "'role1','role2' from array.
string userRolesForSqlQuery = userRoles.Select(x => "'" + x + "'").Aggregate((a,b) => a + "," + b); 


//Psuedo code for querying the database...
var fileForUserQuery = String.Format("SELECT FileID, FileName, FilePath FROM Files 
                           INNER JOIN FilesRole ON Files.FileID = FilesRole.FileID
                           WHERE FilesRole.RoleName IN ({0});", userRolesForSqlQuery);
```

Hopefully this gets you there...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have so far. It works but I know it is not correct because I am doing database stuff in the Controller and that should be done in the model but I can't figure out how to get it done that way.

Model

```
public class files
{
    public int fileid { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string filePath { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IList<files> downloads = new List<files>();
        // Get Users Role(s) thanks Ropstah
        string[] userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name);
        string userRolesForSqlQuery = userRoles.Select(x => "'" + x + "'").Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b);

        // MySql Connection thanks again Ropstah
        string connectionString = "my data source";
        var MySqlConnectionString = String.Format(@"SELECT fileid, fileName, filePath, FROM downloads
                                                    INNER JOIN downloadsroles on downloads.fileid = downloadsroles.downloadsid
                                                    WHERE downloadsroles.roleName IN ({0});", userRolesForSqlQuery);

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        MySqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
        MySqlDataReader Reader;
        comm.CommandText = MySqlConnectionString;
        conn.Open();
        Reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            downloads.Add(new files() { fileName = Reader["fileName"].ToString(),
                                        filePath = Reader["filePath"].ToString()});
        }

        conn.Close();

        return View(downloads);
    }
```

View

```
@foreach (var downloads in ViewData.Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @downloads.fileName
    </td>
    <td>
        @downloads.filePath
    </td>
</tr>
}
```